# Download not working on Stealth Plugin with used with Puppeteer-extra

Tags: puppeteer

appreciate some assistance on the following issue, which seems to be from **Stealth Plugin**. I am using puppeteer to click on a download button in an iframe, which works when I am using Puppeteer, but not when I am using Stealth Plugin.

**The problem: Once the button is clicked, nothing happens, no download is initiated.**

Basically, removing **puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())** makes the entire code work. However I need Stealth Plugin to avoid being detection as an automation browser.

| Libraries | Work/Doesn't work |
| --- | --- |
| Puppeteer | Works |
| Puppeteer-extra | Works |
| Puppeteer-extra + Stealth Plugin | Doesn't work |

Following is a simplified code which I am using:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
(async () => {
   //Setup the browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ["--ignore-certificate-errors"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page._client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    //Initial setup for download
    behavior: "allow",
    downloadPath: downloadPath,
  });
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
  
  await page.goto("***websitehere***");
  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  const frameElement = await page.$("#iframe-analytics");
  const frame = await frameElement.contentFrame();
  await frame.waitForSelector(".table-download-button");
  await frame.click(".table-download-button");
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Button which I'm trying to click on:

```
<button class="table-download-button md-icon-button md-button ng-scope md-scionTheme-theme md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-if="ctrl.csvFormatter" ng-click="ctrl.downloadCsv()" aria-label="Download CSV" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-19">
<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons-extended" class="material-icons-extended ng-scope md-scionTheme-theme" aria-hidden="true" role="img">save_alt</md-icon>
<div class="md-ripple-container"></div></button>
```

Would appreciate if someone could point out what other setting I have to change that's unique on puppeteer extra + stealth plugin.

Comment: Hi @joal welcome to stack overflow. I would recommend reformatting your question to a [minimal and reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help others duplicate your issue, understand your problem better and help you. Also any errors or logs you might have is helpful to include as well.

Comment: @domdambrogia Hi, I have updated the post accordingly. Thank you! There's no error, but simply the button doesn't work, and the download doesn't get initiated.